# NodeJS returns ETIMEDOUT with snmpwalk calling

Tags: snmp

Hi I have a snmpwalk command that takes at least 50 seconds to complete.
I used childprocess to run and wait for its response but I always get this error:

```
Error: spawnSync /bin/sh ETIMEDOUT
```

Here is the code:

```
    const command = `snmpwalk -v2c -On -c ABCDEF123 ${arg_ip} ${arg_oid}`;
    let output = "";
    try {
        output = childProcess.execSync(command, {timeout: 25000, maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 * 2});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(command, e.toString());
        throw new AppError({message: 'Error: Command failed'});
    }
```

Is there any suggestion for handle such a long command?
I tried some 3rd lib but nothing helps.

Comment: For SNMP v2 and above you should use `snmpbulkwalk`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you are passing 25000ms that is equivalent to 25 seconds, setting it to 50000ms might work. Something like

```
  const command = `snmpwalk -v2c -On -c ABCDEF123 ${arg_ip} ${arg_oid}`;
let output = "";
try {
    output = childProcess.execSync(command, {timeout: 51000, maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 * 2});
} catch (e) {
    console.log(command, e.toString());
    throw new AppError({message: 'Error: Command failed'});
}
```

(Extra 1 second margin)